# Я могу раздавать лишь один конкретный файл, а остальные нет

Tags: python, python-3.x, torrent

Я создаю torrent файл вот таким кодом:

```
from torf import Torrent
import datetime as dt

t = Torrent(path='<my_file>.txt',
            trackers=['http://<my_ip>:9000/announce'],
            creation_date=dt.datetime.now())
t.generate()
t.write('<my_file>.txt.torrent')
```

И если я пытаюсь раздавать файл с именем `test3.txt` и содержанием `test3\n` - то всё хорошо, файл раздаётся и я могу его скачать. Но если я пытаюсь раздать файл с тем же содержанием, но с именем `test2.txt`, или любой другой файл - такой файл уже не получается раздавать - и когда я пытаюсь его скачать(использую для этого программу qBittorrent) у этого файла просто стоит статус `Stalled`

Answer (score 0):

Это было потому что файл test3.txt лежал у меня в загрузках, а остальные нет